# Dual monitors: on startup, screenbrightness only changes for one monitor

Tags: 20.04, multiple-monitors, hdmi, brightness, dvi

I am trying to change my default screen brightness on startup. I have added the following script to ~/.config/autostart
screenBrightness.desktop:

```
  [Desktop Entry]                                                                                                                                   
  Encoding=UTF-8                                                                                                                                    
  Version=1.0                                                                                                                                       
  Type=Application                                                                                                                                  
  Name=screenBrightness                                                                                                                             
  Comment=automatically configures the screen brightness at startup                                                                                 
  Exec=xrandr --output DVI-0 --brightness .7 --output HDMI-0 --brightness .7                                                                        
  StartupNotify=false                                                                                                                               
  Terminal=false                                                                                                                                    
  Hidden=false
```

The script definitely executes on startup because the screen brightness level for the HDMI screen changes, but the screen brightness for the DVI screen does not change.

Please note that if I enter the command (the same command in the above script):

```
xrandr --output DVI-0 --brightness .7 --output HDMI-0 --brightness .7
```

The brightness levels change correctly for both screens. I have no idea why the DVI screen brightness will not change on startup, but the HDMI screen does.

I am on ubuntu 20.04.

Edit: as requested, the output of xrandr | grep " connected " | awk '{ print$1 }' is

```
marc@bigBoop:~$ xrandr | grep " connected " | awk '{ print$1 }'
HDMI-0
DVI-0
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `xrandr | grep " connected " | awk '{ print$1 }'?

Comment: @PixelatedFish yes, see above

Comment: Interesting. What happens if you remove that line from the desktop file?

Comment: @PixelatedFish if I remove the exec line from the desktop file, both monitors are at 100% brightness on startup.

Comment: @PixelatedFish note that I also added the command to my .profile out of curiosity, and the behavior was the same: on startup, the HDMI display brightness was at 70% and the DVI display was at 100%. Very strange behavior...

Comment: I wonder if, for some reason, the DVI monitor hasn't been setup by the time that command runs. Maybe try setting the exec command to `bash -c '$(xrandr | grep " connected " | awk '{ print$1 }) >> /tmp/monitors', and post the contents of that file? Not sure if that command would even work in the exec line. Also might want to try in a terminal first.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115146/discussion-between-pixelated-fish-and-marc-soda).